# Angular JS Refresh Specific ID when button click

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, onsen-ui

Im new to AngularJS and im developing mobile web app.
I have few id divs for different views.(thats how AngularJS works right? one HTML page) and i want to use different javascript for specific id Pages. because each ID page should retrieve json Data objects from internet and show in that specific IDs.

im using Chart.js Charts to show data. Problem is for the first time javascript works and charts will be show. but not the second time.

Ex: Menu Bar --> Home page ID | 2nd Page ID | 3rd Page ID

When i go to another page using menu. and again click Home button Data not visible.

I have simple test javascript to load.

```
<script>

    var pieData = [
        {
          value: 300,
          color:"#F7464A",
          highlight: "#FF5A5E",
          label: "Red"
        },
        {
          value: 50,
          color: "#46BFBD",
          highlight: "#5AD3D1",
          label: "Green"
        },
        {
          value: 100,
          color: "#FDB45C",
          highlight: "#FFC870",
          label: "Yellow"
        },
        {
          value: 40,
          color: "#949FB1",
          highlight: "#A8B3C5",
          label: "Grey"
        },
        {
          value: 120,
          color: "#4D5360",
          highlight: "#616774",
          label: "Dark Grey"
        }

      ];

      window.onload = function(){
        var ctx = document.getElementById("chart-area").getContext("2d");
        window.myPie = new Chart(ctx).Pie(pieData);
      };

  </script>
```

I tried putting `onClick="javascript:refreshID();"`to refresh it. didnt work

HTML

```
<ons-list class="menu-list">
        <ons-list-item class="menu-item" onClick="javascript:refreshID();" ng-click="menu.setMainPage('page1.html', {closeMenu: true})">
          <ons-icon icon="fa-plus"></ons-icon>
          Home
        </ons-list-item>


 <ons-template id="page1.html">
    <ons-page>
      <ons-toolbar>
        <div class="left">
          <ons-toolbar-button ng-click="menu.toggle()">
            <ons-icon icon="ion-navicon" size="28px" fixed-width="false"></ons-icon>
          </ons-toolbar-button>
        </div>
        <div class="center"><br/>Welcome to AquaLife</div>
      </ons-toolbar>

      <ons-row style="margin-top: 100px;">
        <ons-col align="center">

        //Chart
          <div id="canvas-holder">
      <canvas id="chart-area" width="300" height="300"/>
    </div>
//Chart

        </ons-col>
      </ons-row>
    </ons-page>
  </ons-template>
```

Comment: Can you show us more of your code?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8ILQOFAgaXE

Answer (score 1):

The angular way is to add that `refreshID()` function to the `$scope` of the view and use `ng-click` to call it.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately that is not how angular.js works,
you will need to create a controller which will be bound to the container of the chart.
then feed the data as property of the controller's $scope and set a $watch property for the scope and bind your resetting function to it

```
window.myPie = new Chart(ctx).Pie(pieData);
```

will look like

```
scope.$watch('name', function(ctx, pieData) {

controllerName.myPie = new Chart(ctx).Pie(pieData);
});
```

and the

```
var ctx = document.getElementById("chart-area").getContext("2d");
```

bit will be in the controller initialization , set ctx as another property

that way every time you change something in your variable you will have the pie reinitialized

If you need more help look at:
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope